# Does ActiveReport always print in EMF format?

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I've made an app that captures the printer Qeue. I'm capturing printjobs made by another app that uses ActiveReports. I need to know if the SPL files of that printjob will always be in EMF format, because i need to convert them into PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the standard Windows print format.   However, ActiveReports does include PDF export with many more features than just capturing the print file.  any reason you don't want to use that?

http://activereports.grapecity.com